# How to read several days log files when use `atopsar`?

Tags: atop

My system is centos 7.4 with `atop-2.3.0-8.el7.x86_64`.
I already have 3 days log in `var/log/atop`, such as `atop_20190312  atop_20190313  atop_20190314`.

I want to find out the peak period of CPU consumption in those 3 days.
Based on [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364359/atop-peak-memory-usage-from-log),I tried:

```
atopsar -r /var/log/atop/ -A -R 3 -c |head
```

but failed.

How to read several days atop log into one?

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry to say that as I know, atopsar is not able to combine several days.

**Selection the date:**

You can use `-r` to directly read one atop-log file. If you need to check yesterday or the day before, you can use `-r y`. If you add `y` you can select even older days: `-r yy` would be the day before yesterday.

**Selection the right report**

You can either select all reports with `-A` or select for example CPU only with `-c`. 
Selecting both doesn't make sense.

**Conclusion**

Since you want to see the cpu utilization for 3 days, you can see them:

```
Today: 
# atopsar  -R 3 -c |head

Yesterday:
# atopsar -r y -R 3 -c |head

2 Days ago:
# atopsar -r y -R 3 -c |head
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: If only one day range, I am sad that's not `statistics`

Comment: what's the meaning of `-R 3` of `atopsar  -R 3 -c |head` ?

Comment: Hi @kittygirl . You started with `-R 3` in your question. It means: Summarize 3 samples into one sample.

Please consult the man pages or https://linux.die.net/man/1/atopsar for more details.

Comment: seemed something  wrong with your answer `2 days ago # atopsar -r y`

Comment: Have a look at `https://superuser.com/questions/599464/graphing-atop-logs/708127?noredirect=1#comment2135038_708127`